# Sticky footer css trick with IE6 not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, sticky-footer

I imagine that this question pops up every now and then (I actually read some posts before posting my own question) but here it is again.

How can I get the sticky footer to work on this url with *IE 6*? (link was removed because it is now broken)

The difference here is that I get a hidden div that shows if you click in "Werknemer" or "AEX" for example.

This is the block that I want to be visible in the bottom of the browser window (not at the end of the page as it currently is).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is ie6 common enough these days that you have to bend backwards to make things compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always done position: fixed in IE with css expressions.  I find it's the least destructive as far as your markup is concerned.  The only catch is that without Javascript enabled, it doesn't work.

Here's what you'd put in an IE6 only stylesheet if you're working in quirks mode:

```
/* Smooths out the scrolling of #your-fixed-element */
body {
  background-attachment: fixed; 
} 

#fixedElement  {
  position: absolute;      
  left: 0;
  top: expression(document.body.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight-this.clientHeight);
}
```

And if you're in standards mode, use this #fixedElement declaration instead:

```
#fixedElement  {
  position: absolute;      
  left: 0;
  top: expression(documentElement.scrollTop+documentElement.clientHeight-this.clientHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for "IE6 position fixed" (`position: fixed` is the CSS you'd use in better browers.)

This site has a fair few solutions: http://www.wickham43.supanet.com/tutorial/headerfooterfix.html
(I'd guess [this example](http://www.wickham43.supanet.com/tutorial/headerfooterfixexample.html) is the one you're looking for)